# How to add list, with LINQ, in an xml?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following structure in an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfNO xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <No>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>txt_1</Name>
    <Text>some text</Text>
    <Txt_relacionados>
      <string>txt_4</string>
      <string>txt_4</string>
      <string>txt_4</string>
    </Txt_relacionados>
    <N>0</N>
    <X>285</X>
    <Y>31</Y>
    <Externa>false</Externa>
    <EM>false</EM>
    <B>false</B>
    <K>false</K>
    <L1>false</L1>
    <L2>false</L2>
    <L3>false</L3>
    <L4>false</L4>
    <L5>false</L5>
    <L6>false</L6>
    <L7>false</L7>
    <L8>false</L8>
    <L9>false</L9>
    <L10>false</L10>
    <L11>false</L11>
    <L12>false</L12>
    <IP>0</IP>
  </No>
```

I'm having trouble inserting the "Txt_relacionados" element because it contains a list of strings.

In the VO of this element i have the following:

```
    [XmlArray("Txt_relacionados"), XmlArrayItem("string", Type = typeof(String))]
    private List<String> txt_relacionados = new List<String>();

    public List<String> Txt_relacionados
    {
        get { return txt_relacionados; }
        set { txt_relacionados = value; }
    }
```

What changes should I make in the code below to be able to insert this list?

```
public void inserir2(VoNo value)
        {
            RefreshXDoc();
            XElement no = XElement.Load(path);

            XElement element = new XElement("No",
                new XElement("Id", value.Id),
                new XElement("Name", value.Name),
                new XElement("Text", value.Text),

                new XmlArrayAttribute("Txt_relacionados", value.Txt_relacionados),

                new XElement("N", value.N),
                new XElement("X", value.X),
                new XElement("Y", value.Y),
                new XElement("Externa", value.Externa),
                new XElement("B", value.B),
                new XElement("K", value.K),
                new XElement("L1", value.L1),
                new XElement("L2", value.L2),
                new XElement("L3", value.L3),
                new XElement("L4", value.L4),
                new XElement("L5", value.L5),
                new XElement("L6", value.L6),
                new XElement("L7", value.L7),
                new XElement("L8", value.L8),
                new XElement("L9", value.L9),
                new XElement("L10", value.L10),
                new XElement("L11", value.L11),
                new XElement("L12", value.L12),
                new XElement("IP", value.IP));

            no.Add(element);
            no.Save(path);
        }
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Strings in txt_relacionados are in specific format from which you can figure out the element name and the value of it? Can you share the format of the strings?

Comment: All strings in this array have the following format: 

txt_ (number)
Example: txt_5; txt_6; txt_10

Comment: What issue you are facing with line `new XmlArrayAttribute("Txt_relacionados", value.Txt_relacionados)`  ? did you consider looping thru the list and creating element for each of the item in the list ?

Comment: The issue is that this method only accepts one argument of type string. I've tried putting only "Txt_relacionados" as an argument. However, the result is not the correct structure.

Instead of generating:

     `<Text>SomeText</Text>
     <Txt_relacionados>
        <string>txt_17</string>
     </Txt_relacionados>
     <N>2</N>`

It is generated:

     `<Text> SomeText</ Text>
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute
     <N> 0 </ N>`

In fact I would just like to create the right structure, even if empty and of no value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `Txt_relacionados` element before you create new element `No` and then pass `Txt_relacionados` at proper place when you are creating `No`.

Consider following.

```
public void inserir2(VoNo value)
{
    var rels = new XElement("Txt_relacionados");

    foreach (var x in value.Txt_relacionados)
    {
        var elem = new XElement("string", x);
        rels.Add(elem);
    }

    RefreshXDoc();
    XElement no = XElement.Load(path);

    XElement element = new XElement("No",
    new XElement("Id", value.Id),
    new XElement("Name", value.Name),
    new XElement("Text", value.Text),
    rels,
    new XElement("N", value.N),
    new XElement("X", value.X),
    new XElement("Y", value.Y),
    new XElement("Externa", value.Externa),
    new XElement("B", value.B),
    new XElement("K", value.K),
    new XElement("L1", value.L1),
    new XElement("L2", value.L2),
    new XElement("L3", value.L3),
    new XElement("L4", value.L4),
    new XElement("L5", value.L5),
    new XElement("L6", value.L6),
    new XElement("L7", value.L7),
    new XElement("L8", value.L8),
    new XElement("L9", value.L9),
    new XElement("L10", value.L10),
    new XElement("L11", value.L11),
    new XElement("L12", value.L12),
    new XElement("IP", value.IP));

    no.Add(element);
    no.Save(path);
}
```